# named_scope in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have two models.. **Member** and **MemberMeeting** .

Member has_many member_meetings.

I have written a named_scope in **Member** model such that it does a join operation on the member_meetings.

Now the hard part,

I have a boolean column xyz. I need to check for count(xyz=true) > 1 inside the named_scope

Comment: How does your actual code look like? In particular the named scope you already have. Is `xyz` a column of the `member_meetings` table?

Comment: yes.. xyz is a boolena column in member_meetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want a scope for this? I assume you want a list of all members that have more than one meeting where xyz is true, right? In that case, something like this should do:

```
members = Member.include(:member_meetings)
members.select{ |m| m.member_meetings.select(&:xyz).size > 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this named_scope to Member should do it:

```
named_scope :my_scope, :include => :member_meetings, :conditions => { 'member_meetings.xyz' => true }
```